# The TFF style is not displaying correctly, and the configured attributes are not being displayed correctly

Tags: qgis, geoserver, style, sld, xml

（1）I imported the SLD exported from QGIS into GeoServer, but I noticed that the font symbols displayed are completely different in shape from what I see in QGIS, as shown in the image below.
geoserver
[image]

QGIS（I've noticed that in QGIS, when I view a particular character, the 'Character' field displays one representation, while the 'Preview' field displays another representation. However, in GeoServer, it displays the result from the 'Character' field.）
[image]
（2）I've noticed that the attributes I've configured for the TFF symbol, except for the color, are not being accurately represented. For example, the symbol's offset is not applied. Could it be an issue with my XML formatting? I couldn't find any documentation related to offsets on the official website tutorial.
[image]
My XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>p6_治理恢复</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>p6_治理恢复</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>耕地恢复</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>耕地恢复</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>tblx</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>耕地恢复</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f8d072</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Cartography#0xc8</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#70a800</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>10</se:Size>
                  <se:Displacement>
                    <se:DisplacementX>5</se:DisplacementX>
                    <se:DisplacementY>-1</se:DisplacementY>
                  </se:Displacement>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="distance">50,50</se:VendorOption>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Cartography#0xc8</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#70a800</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>10</se:Size>
                  <se:Displacement>
                    <se:DisplacementX>9</se:DisplacementX>
                    <se:DisplacementY>2</se:DisplacementY>
                  </se:Displacement>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="distance">50,50</se:VendorOption>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>      
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I have provided GeoServer log information with the log level set to 'geoserver developer'.

```
19 9月 17:41:50 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of E:\1_geoserver\1_ServerSite\2_GeoServerData\gwc-layers
19 9月 17:41:50 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for E:\1_geoserver\1_ServerSite\2_GeoServerData\gwc-layers
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/web/**'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/rest/**'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426'; against '/**'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Request matched by universal pattern '/**'
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Matched Path: /style_test/wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=style_test%3Ap6_GovernanceRecovery&STYLES=style_test%3AGovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913&FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout%3Astyle-editor-legend%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&RANDOM=-1945430352&LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels%3Aon%3BfontAntiAliasing%3Atrue&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=897&HEIGHT=707&BBOX=35.134159326553345%2C108.1550681591034%2C35.14932990074158%2C108.17431569099426 with /**
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource$LoginPageRequestMatcher@6f944b94 - [] (1/4)
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/web/resources/**'] - [] (2/4)
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/config/**'] - [ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR] (3/4)
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@17c1d87] and 1 interceptors
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [ows.Dispatcher] - Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'forceLabels'. Storing as raw string.
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'fontAntiAliasing'. Storing as raw string.
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'layout'. Storing as raw string.
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find kvp parser for: 'fontAntiAliasing'. Storing as raw string.
19 9月 17:41:53 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - establishing GovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913 style for p6_GovernanceRecovery
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.wms] - setting up map
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.wms] - setting up 897x707 image
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - setting to transparent
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - Configured MarkFactory precedence found: [TTFMarkFactory, WellKnownMarkFactory, QGISMarkFactory, ShapeMarkFactory, WKTMarkFactory, MeteoMarkFactory, WindBarbsFactory, SVGMarkFactory]
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - setting to transparent
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - setting to transparent
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - setting to transparent
19 9月 17:41:53 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://192.168.40.161:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[35.134159326553345 : 35.14932990074158, 108.1550681591034 : 108.17431569099426]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {FONTANTIALIASING=true, LAYOUT=style-editor-legend}
    Get = true
    Height = 707
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@5179d2f1]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/png, CRS=EPSG:4326, RANDOM=-1945430352, STYLES=style_test:GovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913, WIDTH=897, HEIGHT=707, LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels:on;fontAntiAliasing:true, LAYERS=style_test:p6_GovernanceRecovery, EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage, REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT_OPTIONS=layout:style-editor-legend;fontAntiAliasing:true, BBOX=35.134159326553345,108.1550681591034,35.14932990074158,108.17431569099426, VERSION=1.3.0, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=GovernanceRecovery_lyr-qml-sld_20230913]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.3.0
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 897
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - Writing png image ...
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
19 9月 17:41:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: displacements only apply to **`TextSymbolizer`** not fills so they will be ignored

Comment: I have adjusted the log level and checked the logs, but I did not find any errors. I have posted the logs in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: You're looking for a line like `TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name ttf://Original Surfer#0x2318` and I need to see what follows that

Comment: I have checked the logs, and there are no issues related to what you mentioned (related to the renderer). However, I did find something that matches what I mentioned in my previous message. When viewing this character in QGIS, there are two different representations. I'm not sure if this is related to the issue.

Comment: If possible, I can send the font to you via email, and you can give it a try

Comment: You can raise a bug with all the details and a copy of the font - but whether anyone will feel the need to fix it is a different matter

Comment: Okay, I understand. I think resolving this issue will help ArcGIS Server users migrate to GeoServer, haha. I will continue to follow up on this matter, and if I find a solution, I will come back to let everyone know.